# Dialog box icon

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-theme

I have the following script where I have been trying to customise the look and feel of the dialog box:

http://jsfiddle.net/7CvZ9/18/

However, I can't seem to figure out how to customise the close icon.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I have customised other parts of the dialog but looking at the theme api:

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

But from that link, I can't figure out how to customise the close icon.

So basically, I want to replace the existing 2 state image, with my own 2 state image sprite file.

Comment: In what way do you want to customize the icon?

Comment: For example, create my own close icon image ( I'm assuming it's an image? ) which has 2 states just like the default image.  As at the moment, it looks out of place when compared with other icons in my application which are manually built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    /* Default image */
    background-image:url('http://www.charlottemotorspeedway.com/images/icon_x.png');
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover,
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close:focus {
    background-color:transparent !important;
    border:none !important;
    /* Hover state image */
    background-image:url('http://www.charlottemotorspeedway.com/images/icon_x.png') !important;
}
```

Example, I swapped out the X for a new image: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/7CvZ9/22/

Comment: THat is very close to what I was after.  Is is possible to change the mouse over effect?  As I originally thought that was part of the icon, looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery ui theme contains sprite images of all the icons grouped together and organzined in the same file.

You can change the icons in your customized theme file.

the files are named something like: `ui-icons_222222_256x240.png`

and can be foudn in the `images` folder of the theme

the image looks something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The class involved in the close icon are:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close 
.ui-icon-closethick
```

This is the generated markup

```
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
</a>
```

i think you should override those two classes to change the way the button looks

Comment: If I have my own sprite icon file, how to I apply the default state of any image as the default state, then another on the hover state?